# Add flashlight to ionic react project

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, rect, ionic-react

Trying to add flashlight to ionic react project for a barcode scanner app, could not find any documentation whatsoever on implementing it in ionic react. Any links to sites with how to solve this would be great. The only documentation I can find is about using it in ionic angular
Tried using cordova flashlight plugin but its not working requires angular/core

Answer (score 1):

had to install rjxs and ionic/core for it to work

Comment: Was it generating an error ?

Comment: yes at first it was looking for the ionic/core module, installed that got another error, showed that rxjs was missing installed it. Now its working

Answer (score 0):

Always check the developer's [github](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Flashlight-PhoneGap-Plugin) page, they're more documented than ionic.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, unfortunately its the same issue, they havent documented it for ionic react